# AngularJS: looping through a list of objects returned by a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller to get some data from an API:

```
.controller('MyDataController', ['$http', function($http) {

    pdc = this;
    pdc.projects = []

    pdc.getData = function(val) {
        return $http.get('../myUrl/'+val+"/").then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        });
    };    

}]);
```

I'm trying to loop through response data (a list of object like `[{"foo":3, "bar":"hey"},{...},...,{...}]`), calling `getData` every time user changes `myValue`. This is the code:

```
<div ng-controller = "MyDataController as mdc">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myValue">
    <p ng-repeat="myData in mdc.getData(myValue)">{{myData.foo}}</p>
</div>
```

...but it does not work. It seems there is a problem on ng-repeat, how can I fix?

Comment: Did you notice the `mdc"">`. Double quotes? Or is that a typo?

Comment: Look at the console. You must be seeing infinite digest error, also ng-repeat cannot resolve promise to value as it is. Assign value to a property and use it in ng-repeat

Comment: @RoyMJ Thanks it was a mistake

Comment: @PSL Yep, I see the infinite error. If I have understood your hint, I have to assign resposnse data to a property like `pdc.property = response.data` and then `ng-repeat  = "myData in mdc.property"`. I tried but it doesn't work :( I think Angular doesn't trigger the function when `myValue` changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the right way to go about it:

```
.controller('MyDataController', ['$http', function($http) {
    pdc = this;
    pdc.projects = [];

    pdc.getData = function(val) {
        return $http.get('../myUrl/'+val+"/").then(function(response){
            pdc.data = response.data;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Then update your markup as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="MyDataController as mdc"">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myValue" ng-change="mdc.getData(myValue)">
    <p ng-repeat="myData in mdc.data()">{{myData.foo}}</p>
</div>
```

Why wasn't your original code giving the expected outcome?

- At the time `getData` is called, what you get is a promise for the data that will possibly be available later. You don't get the data then.
- Returning `response.data` where you did, does not achieve your aim because that success function is not directly connected to your `getData`.
- Angular updates your view when there's a change in the scope. After the data was returned from your request, there's nothing to suggest that anything has changed. You should make an assignment to some property in your scope to trigger a view update (there are other ways to achieve that, but that i have said what you currently need to know). The expression `"MyDataController as mdc"` adds your controller to the scope, and with this addition changes in the controller object will trigger a view update.

Comment: Thanks! It works very fine in that example! My code is a bit more complex: `myValue` is a variable which contains an object read from Session Storage, so I can't use `ng-change` :(

Comment: No big deal.. Well you know better, but whenever you read a new value from session storage you may manually call `mdc.getData(myValue);`.

Comment: Yep! I added a `$scope.$watch` on Session Storage to assign to `myValue` the new object data every time it changes. My idea was to loop through a list of the objects returned by `getData` every time `myValue` is updated. I tried this way: `<p ng-repeat="myData in mdc.getData(myValue)">{{myData.foo}}</p>` but I obtain an infinite loop...

Answer (score 0):

For sure this is not the only way to do it... but works fine

*The controller...*

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyDataController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.values = [];

    $scope.$watch('myValue', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
             return $http.get('../myUrl/'+newValue+'/').then(function(response){
                   $scope.values = response.data;
             });
        }
    });

}]);
```

*The view...*

```
 <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MyDataController">
        <input ng-model="myValue" type="text" />
        <p ng-repeat="myData in values">{{myData.foo}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Try it in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csq6sh9j/)